# SET-Sharepoint 2016 list multiple lines of text default value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, 2016, multiple-lines-of-text

How to set default value in SharePoint 2016 list multiple lines of text field (Enhanced rich text ) using SharePoint designer new form.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Open the site in SharePoint Designer 2013.
2. Select **List and Libraries** and select the list.
3. Select **Edit list columns**.
4. Double click on the multi-line text field.
5. Edit the Default value.
6. Save.

**Source**: [Add default text to a multi-line text field](https://myspquestions.wordpress.com/add-default-text-to-a-multi-line-text-field/).

Comment: Have you tried this? Is it working for you?

Comment: probably you forgot the first point 0. Find SharePoint Designer 2013 and install it

Comment: also, 0.1 install the SP1 of SharePoint Designer